# Basic Galois theory question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension, and $\bar{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$.

If we consider the following grups:

- $G \cong Gal(\bar{K}/\mathbb{Q})$
- $H \cong Gal(\bar{K}/K)$

Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and applying the main theorem of Galois theory,

$$Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G/H$$

> Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Warning: you need to be careful when using infinite extensions and Galois theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $\psi:Gal(\bar K/\mathbb Q)\longrightarrow Gal(K/\mathbb Q)$ be the restriction, i.e. $\psi(\sigma )=\sigma |_K$. It's easy (more or less... it's in fact important to prove this result) to see that $\psi$ is surjective and that $\ker \psi=Gal(\bar K/K)$, what gives you the isomorphism.